# Database Integrity check fails as follows

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren, dbcc-checkdb

(I have used the Ola Hallengren scripts for quite a while)....but if there is an open query I end up with the following:

Msg 5030, Sev 16, State 12, Line 1 : The database could not be exclusively locked to perform the operation. [SQLSTATE 42000]
Msg 7926, Sev 16, State 1, Line 1 : Check statement aborted. The database could not be checked as a database snapshot could not be created and the database or table could not be locked. See Microsoft Knowledge Base article 928518

Parameters: @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES', @CheckCommands = 'CHECKDB', @PhysicalOnly = 'N', @DataPurity = 'N', @NoIndex = 'N', @ExtendedLogicalChecks = 'N', @TabLock = 'N', @FileGroups = NULL, @Objects = NULL, @MaxDOP = NULL, @AvailabilityGroups = NULL, @AvailabilityGroupReplicas = 'ALL', @Updateability = 'ALL', @TimeLimit = NULL, @LockTimeout = NULL, @LockMessageSeverity = 16, @StringDelimiter = ',', @DatabaseOrder = NULL, @DatabasesInParallel = 'N', @LogToTable = 'Y', @Execute = 'Y'
Some of my databases have not had the check completed for a long time.
Is there a way to bypass/rectify this issue somehow?

Regards Ian

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. Could you possibly provide more details? Which jobs are you automatically executing and what are the actual job steps? The community will be unable to provide a solution without further information / details. Click on [edit] and add the missing bits to your question. Thanks. (please also consider reading up on [ask])

Comment: Microsoft Knowledge Base article 928518 claims this issue being fixed in Cumulative Update 4 for SQL Server 2014 SP1. What version of SQL do you run?

Comment: I've added the step command that is generated by the OH script

Comment: We are running SQL 2019 Standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that in my root volume when the dbs are stored I’d reduced the default permissions – ostensibly to tighten security.

I needed one of the 4 accounts below to have READ permission on the root volume (this is why the system databases worked as they were in a different location)

1. SQL Server Service Account
2. Everyone
3. NT Authority\Authenticated Users
4. Users (e.g. TestServer\Users). This group usually includes NT Authority\Authenticated Users

I couldn’t use the system account as they vary with instance so I added Authenticated Users back in to the root of D with READ permission to that folder only and hey presto……eureka and any other word IT WORKED

Thanks must go to the following article (first time I’ve come across it, must have been my search parameters this time):

https://www.travisgan.com/2013/11/dbcc-checkdb-database-snapshot-failure.html

At last …. so chuffed, will be a few beers tonight